# Is it benificial to take off rest days between bodyweight workouts?

Tags: workout-routines, workout

My regular workout consists of about 3/4 sets of 90 pushups and furthermore some situps. I am 19 years old. Would it be bad to do this workout (almost) every day of the week? And would doing it as often as possible give me maximal results or would I get better results if I took days of rest in between? If so, how many days a week should I work out?

Comment: What results are you looking for?

Comment: More muscles. Im trying to extend my sixpack as much as possible.

Comment: Trust your body, if you feel like you can skip your rest day then go ahead. Be careful though, over-training is really easy to do, especially if you arn't eating right.

Comment: Well, i smell a XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Basically you want a six pack, but instead of asking us whats the best way to get it you ask us how to do what you do better. Please check out questions on developing a six pack, and come clarify what exactly do you need to know if those wont answer your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking *at least* one day off for some light cardio/stretching/yoga per week.

That said, you should not be working the same two muscle groups on consecutive days. Your body needs time to repair the broken down muscles and cannot adequately do so in ~24 hours. I would recommend working in exercises that target different muscle groups for optimal repair and gains.

Answer (score 0):

Over training is incredibly hard to get to, elite athletes train every day, heavy without signs of overtraining[(1)](https://mennohenselmans.com/training-frequency-3x-vs-6x/)

Also Schoenfeld conducted a study where he compared the effects of different training volumes on the average gym rats.

Even though people in the experiment were doing 45 sets, weekly for their legs they have experienced 0 signs of overtraining while having bigger muscle growth effects than the lower volume groups.